# Missing repository in POM file

Tags: java, maven

I have a POM file

```
    <repositories>    
  <repository>
    <id>bedatadriven</id>
    <name>bedatadriven public repo</name>
    <url>https://nexus.bedatadriven.com/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>       
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera.repo</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
            <name>Cloudera Repositories</name>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vroc</id>
            <url>http://repo.vroc.ai:8081/repository/maven-vroc/</url>
            <name>VROC Repo</name>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>vroc</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.vroc.ai:8081/repository/maven-vroc/</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>vroc</id>
            <name>Snapshot</name>
            <url>http://repo.vroc.ai:8081/repository/maven-vroc/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.renjin</groupId>
    <artifactId>renjin-script-engine</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2527</version>
  </dependency>

    ....
```

when I run my project it gives below exception. I am not sure how to resolve it

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mdm: Could not resolve dependencies for project ai.vroc:mdm:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.renjin:renjin-script-engine:jar:0.8.2527 in vroc (http://repo.vroc.ai:8081/repository/maven-public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

The dependency which gives error is in "bedatadriven" repository but it can not find it. I am not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: is there any suggestion? this one always downloads from the first repository..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this to be a version in your maven repo

```
<version>0.8.2527</version>
```

You will need to browse through http://repo.vroc.ai:8081/repository/maven-public yourself since this is not public (at least to me)

Go to org  > renjin > renjin-script-engine, then see what versions are there if any